# Using gRPC over the Internet

Tags: grpc, http2

I am developing an application that needs to connect from an enterprise network to a service in the cloud.
I would like to use gRPC and also gRPC streaming as the protocol for this communication.

Is this going to work? Will routers, proxies and firewalls handle this protocol correctly?
For example, many enterprises have a bluecoat or other proxy at the exit of their network - will it work?

Thanks in advance for your feedback!

Comment: To clarify, I want to know if the leading routers, proxies, load-balancers, firewalls etc. support: gRPC and gRPC streaming

Answer (score 7):

Since HTTP/2 is encrypted and goes over port 443, it would work in many enterprise environments. gRPC implementations don't support WPAD nor SOCKS, but they do support HTTP Forward Proxies (via HTTP CONNECT). If you can use `curl` you can probably use gRPC.

However, some firewalls are configured to Man-in-the-Middle TLS connections and these could be confused by HTTP/2 or disallow its usage. To test this, run curl 7.47.0 or later and see if you get similar output:

```
$ curl -vso /dev/null https://example.com 2>&1 | grep "Using HTTP2"
* Using HTTP2, server supports multi-use
```

Comment: In OS-X, the default version of curl, or even the one provided by Homebrew doesn't support http2. We need to explicitly compile with nghttp2